# How to correctly Dispose of a plugin making sure all open service calls are closed

Tags: c#, wcf, plugins

I currently have a plugin using the basic Add-In model. (using an interface defined in a shared library and using Activator.CreateInstance to create an instance of the plugin) but am unsure how to dispose of it making sure that all open service calls are closed. Currently if I click the close button on a plugin I call

```
 base.Dispose(true);
```

on the user control. Now while this makes the window the plugin is being hosted in disappear I notice that my service call carries on and comes back into the code where it would have been as if the services are not being disposed of correctly.

Is there a correct way to dispose of a plugin making sure that all service calls etc are disposed of?

Comment: Do you actually expect us to know what sort of "plugin" you are talking about?

Comment: To be quite honest, until posting this question I had no idea there were different types of plugins. I have now edited the question to help make it clearer.. I think?

Comment: You _still_ haven't told us anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what type of "plugin" you are using here are a few pointers:

1. Try to use .NET **CancellationToken** or some other means to cancel the operation or in this case indicate that upon returning from the service call, not to bother proceeding
2. Host your plug-in in separate .NET **AppDomains**.  Then when you call [AppDomain.Unload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload(v=vs.110).aspx) it immediately removes the **AppDomain** and everything in it.  This is extremely useful when you want to "delete" something without worrying *"Oh has it been garbage collected yet"* or remembering to call **Dispose**.  It will most likely depend on what comms choice you are using as to the effect of unloading an **AppDomain** hosting a service call mid-call.
3. Close the window
4. **Dispose** the plugin
5. Call **AppDomain.Unload()**

> This is yet another way the AppDomain boundary adds value: it lets you reclaim system resources without having to cycle the process.
>   If the host wants to shut down an add-in immediately, it doesn't have to worry about keeping track of which add-in belongs in which AppDomain. .NET Application Extensibility, MSDN Magazine

Since that article was written, Microsoft created **Managed Addin Framework** (MAF).  MAF supports **AppDomains**.

You can also use async service methods, makes it a bit easier to cancel

**EDIT: The bible on AppDomains; how to use it; how to create and communicate with objects inside another AppDomain can be found in this MSDN article** [Discover Techniques for Safely Hosting Untrusted Add-Ins with the .NET Framework 2.0, MSDN Magazine, November 2005](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineNovember2005en-us.chm)

### MSDN Magazine Archive Update

MS have removed older MSDN Mag direct-for-view articles from their website.

> Note: 2008 and older issues are only available as .chm files. On most versions of windows you must first save these files to your local machine, and then unblock the file in order to read it. To unblock a file, right click on it, and select properties, and then select the ‘unblock’ button. The content will then be available to read - [Tell me more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee310108.aspx)

Comment: Brilliant Answer. I will definitely look into all these options. The Appdomain option seems like it may best suit my needs

Comment: as an update I am currently using object obj = Activator.CreateInstance((Type)enumerator.Current) to create the instances of my plugins if you had any more pointers in the right direction? I am trying to convert this to load each Type in a seperate AppDomain

Comment: @user1 - see my revised answer above to the new MSDN article link, all is revealed there

Comment: @MickyDuncan. That link to MSDN magazine may need updating. You don't happen to remember which issue it was do you?

Comment: @PaulG Sorry about that.  Updated.  It's **November 2005**.  Very sad to see they've pulled older versions and to make them available as .chm files of all things